# How to read kubernetes containers environment variables in angular appilcation

Tags: angular, kubernetes, containers

How to read kubernetes containers environment variables in angular appilcation.
For feature flag.
Application need is :
we can enable or disbale any feature wihtout deploy the code.

Comment: The Angular app runs in your users' browsers, it can't access env vars on the backend.

Comment: So it mean there is not way to read this variable , we have to look for some other options.

Comment: Yes, either build time or run time configuration - I'd recommend the latter, I wrote about it on my blog https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: I goes through your blog, its well explain but runtime we change the window object that will be only the session, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly impossible. As mentioned in the comments, at best you mean to be changing the build process to inject some values from the env, but that should be happening at container build time, not runtime. The way you do this is to put those env vars in your backend API somewhere and expose them via a web API that angular can query at startup.